# With the Crossbow expert feat, can you use a net attack and then a hand crossbow attack on your bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons

Assume that the hand crossbow is already loaded, you first use an action to attack with a net, then use your bonus action to fire your hand crossbow (and also reload it for next turn because you now have a hand free).

My only concern is (under special weapons on PHB p. 148) it says:

> When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction
>   to attack with a net, you can make only one attack
>   regardless of the number of attacks you can
>   normally make.

I take this to mean that if I had multiple attacks (such as a 5th level fighter) I could only take 1 attack with the net even though my attack action allows me more.  In common sense you toss the net as your attack and don't have it to make multiple attacks. But this should not stop you from taking a bonus action to fire your hand crossbow.

Please use RAW whether you are confirming or denying the use of a net and hand crossbow in the same turn.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## The answer is yes.

> Crossbow Expert: the third benefit works with a net, since the net is used with its own action. - Jeremy Crawford (https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/756180214565122048?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

### What the Net Rule Means

You can't use other secondary attacks in the same "action" as the net attack. It has nothing to do with "losing" the net. Because:

> When you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

Is not limited to just attacks with the net. This is limiting use with secondary attack features like the fighters:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of
>   once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn
>   The number of attacks increases to three when you
>   reach 11th level in this class and to four when you reach
>   20th level in this class.

Which is two attacks with one action.  Careful reading of what Jeremy's post indicates you couldn't make a second attack with a sword in the same action/bonus action/reaction the net is thrown, but you could use a different action/bonus action/reaction to do it if you have it available.

The net rule is poorly worded, but from Jeremy's post, it is clear this is what is meant by it.

### The Feat

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you are holding.

Allows you to make an attack as a bonus action, not part of the action.  So you can use the net on the action, and the cross bow on the bonus action. No net rule violated.

Comment: You may want to consider editing - Adamind took out the bit of his answer that you're arguing against.

Comment: No, he didn't.  First paragraph "From what I understand of the special rule for the net, if you make a normal attack with it, you "lose" the net, and this is the reason you cannot attack anymore."

Comment: I still edited it, to future proof the answer in case he does remove that section though.

Comment: I think it's a better answer for it.  +1 for a solid explanation.

Answer (score 10):

I would say **yes** :

From what I understand of the special rule for the net, if you make a normal attack with it, you "lose" the net, and this is the reason you cannot attack anymore. You still can use your bonus action or reaction with another weapon.

The rule specify that you can attack with the net with a bonus action or reaction, so if you are a level 5 fighter, nothing forbids you to use 2 attacks normally with a sword, end your turn and then using your net as a reaction triggered by an attack of opportunity.

If you can do that, the inverse is possible too.

[The issue has been answered by Jeremy Crawford's sage advice](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/03/can-a-pc-with-crossbow-expert-attack-with-a-net-and-then-with-an-hand-crossbow/) and the answer is yes (thanks to @Reibello for the information)

Comment: Had to downvote due to the last paragraph. There is nothing in the rules that say the restriction only applies to the net. "*[w]hen you use an action…to attack with a net, you can make only one attack regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.*" It doesn't say you can't attack multiple times *with the net*, it says *you can make only one attack*.

Comment: I thought that it applies to the net because the rules are written in the net only as a special rule. But i understand your point, what I written last is based on my understanding and not RAW.

Comment: Your logic stands up without the last paragraph.

Comment: I removed my last paragraph because as stated by Christopher and KorvinStarmast it didn't make sense

Comment: @Adamind This issue has been Sage Advice'd if you want to incorporate it - http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/03/can-a-pc-with-crossbow-expert-attack-with-a-net-and-then-with-an-hand-crossbow/